# Windows LIve Sync for Mac?

Tags: mac, software-rec, sync

I recently have switched to mainly using Apple computers.

I used to use Windows Live Sync to keep some documents up to date across computers, but noticed that some people have had trouble on Snow Leopard.

Does anyone have a preferred Mac solution to the file syncing problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can give [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) a try. It's a similar approach and supports Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: Yep, Dropbox is the one! Has an iPhone app as well, which makes viewing files easy on the go.